# Algebraic structures on graphs

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, graph-theory

There are many algebraic structures linked to graphs.

For example one can find zero divisor graphs $[1]$, $[2]$ and many other graphs.

> Does there exist any survey paper which characterizes all the graphs obtained till now from algebraic structures?

If someone could provide any survey article which can give some light, I will be grateful

$[1]$ Anderson, D.F. and Livingston, P.S., 1999. The zero-divisor graph of a commutative ring. Journal of Algebra, 217(2), pp.434-447.

$[2]$ Babai, L., 1979. Spectra of Cayley graphs. Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 27(2), pp.180-189.

Comment: you could see the papers by Prof. Ayman Badawi at [this](https://www.aus.edu/faculty/professor-ayman-badawi) link. He has worked on Total graph of a ring, annihilator graph of a ring, etc.

Comment: @vidyarthi; can you provide a more detailed answer if possibe